# Tengo que crear un programa que al yo ingresar tres dígitos me forme el mayor numero posible con las cifras ingresadas

Tags: c++

**Este es el programa que llevo, pero no me funciona y no se que mas hacer (Soy estudiante principiante)**

```
    #include<iostream>
 
 using namespace std;
 
 ;int num1,resultado,mayor,menor,medio,decena,centena,unidad,calculo;
 int main (){
 
 

 
cout<<"Ingrese un numero de tres cifras=";
cin>>num1;
  
    if ((num1>100&num1<999)(num1>=-999&num1=<-100))
    
    calculo=num1;
    
    if(num1<0)
    centena=num1/100 ;
    centena=(num1%100)/10 ;
    unidad=(num1%100)%10 ;
    menor=centena ;  
  
  
  if (decena<menor) ;
  menor=decena ;

  
 if(unidad<menor) ;
  menor=unidad ;
  mayor=centena ;
  
  if(decena>mayor) ;
  mayor=decena ;
  
  if(unidad>mayor) ;
  mayor=unidad ;
  medio=centena+decena+unidad-mayor-menor ;
  
  if(calculo>0) ;
  resultado=mayor*100+medio*10+menor ;
  cout<<"es "<<resultado<<endl ;
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por empezar revisa la sintaxis del código. Tienes un montón de ; en lugares que no van.

Comment: Una forma que se me ocurre es ubicar los dígitos en un arreglo y ordenarlos con algún algoritmo, que de ese tipo hay muchos y puedes elegir el más sencillo, el más rápido o el que más te guste.

Answer (score 5):

No suelo contestar esta clase de preguntas, pero se nota que te hace falta
consejo.

Vamos por tu código linea a linea, y después hablemos de una solución que
funcione bien.

### Los problemas en tu código

```cpp
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
```

El `using namespace std;` es una muy mala practica. No me extenderé en ello, ya
que de momento no te afectara en mucho. Pero te recomiendo bastante investigar
porque es malo, y que alternativas tienes.

```cpp
;int num1,resultado,mayor,menor,medio,decena,centena,unidad,calculo;
```

Aquí no es necesario que inicies tu linea con un `;`. Ademas de que tener todas
las declaraciones de las variables en la misma linea afecta mucho a la
legibilidad del código.

Una mejora seria:

```cpp
     int num1 = 0;
     int resultado = 0;
     int mayor = 0;
     int menor = 0;
     int medio = 0;
     int decena = 0;
     int centena = 0;
     int unidad = 0;
     int calculo = 0;
```

En la que se ven claramente los nombres de las variables. (Y nota que están
todas inicializadas, que hagas esto por defecto te ahorrara problemas en un
futuro).

Pero esto aun es malo, ya que no esta claro donde es que vas a utilizar cada
variable. Es mucho mejor declararlas donde las uses. (En esto veremos mas
adelante).

Luego este es un problema en todos tus `if`s:

```cpp
    if(num1<0)
    centena=num1/100 ;
    centena=(num1%100)/10 ;
    unidad=(num1%100)%10 ;
    menor=centena ;
```

Que instrucciones son las que están adentro del `if`? Supongo que sera todo el
bloque, pero eso no es claro, y tampoco es correcto.

La sintaxis de los `if` en C++ es:

```
if (condicion) {
    // Codigo
}
```

Y de esa forma deberías escribirlos. Todavía este ultimo ejecutara la primera
instrucción después del `if` si la condición es verdadera. Pero este:

```cpp
 if(unidad<menor) ;
  menor=unidad ;
  mayor=centena ;
```

Directamente no hará nada luego de evaluar la condición.

Y como puedo darme cuenta de esos errores? La verdad es que no hace falta que
le preguntes a nadie, tu compilador es capaz de decírtelos. No se que
compilador usas, así que tendrás que googlear por tu cuenta como poner los
avisos al máximo nivel en el que uses.

**PD:** Ya compilando me di cuenta de esto:

```cpp
    if ((num1>100&num1<999)(num1>=-999&num1=<-100))
```

Supongo que querías hacer algo así como:

```cpp
    if ((num1>100 && num1<999) && (num1>=-999 && num1<=-100))
```

Hay que prestar atención a la sintaxis del lenguaje.

**PD2:** Porfavor, acostúmbrate a indentar tu código, eso ayudara mucho
a entenderlo.

### Una base

Por cuestiones de principio, no te voy a dar una solución que tu puedas
entregar. Eso eliminaría completamente el propósito de que te dejaran la tarea,
ya que no aprenderías nada.

Lo que si puedo dejarte son las bases, para que tu trabajes alrededor de ellas.

No se cuantos temas has tratado en clase de programación, por tu código parece
que únicamente lo mínimo, así que basare lo que te de en eso.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numero = 0;

    cout << "Ingrese un numero de 3 digitos: ";
    cin >> numero;

    if (numero < 100 || numero > 999) {
        cout << numero << "No cumple con los requisitos, vuelva a intentar\n";
        return 1;
    }

    int digito3 = numero % 10;
    int digito2 = ((numero % 100) - digito3)/10;
    int digito1 = numero / 100; // Como los enteros siempre aproximan hacia
                                // abajo, para el mas grande se puede hacer
                                // de esta manera

    int mayor = 0;
    int menor = 0;
    int medio = 0;

    // Aqui coloca tu tus comparaciones para ver cual es el mayor, menor y medio

    cout << "El numero mas grande que se puede crear es: " << mayor << medio
         << menor << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

### Una solución para estudiar

Esta solución ni en broma te la aceptan, ya que si la presentas sera claro que
la copiaste de Internet. No te la pongo aquí por eso, sino porque creo que si
te pones a leerla, y vas buscando en Internet cada cosa, puede que aprendas
algo que te sea útil.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

// Las funciones son muy bunenas para organizar tu codigo
int to_digit(char c) {
    return c - '0';
}

int main(void) {
    constexpr size_t cantidad_digitos = 3; // Siempre es buena idea utilizar
                                           // constantes en lugar de numeros
                                           // magicos
    
    // Busca lo que es un array. Es mucho mejor para guardar colecciones de
    // datos
    std::array<int, cantidad_digitos> digitos{};

    std::cout << "Ingrese un numero de " << cantidad_digitos << " digitos: ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cantidad_digitos; ++i) {
        char c = '\0';
        std::cin >> c;
        digitos[i] = to_digit(c);
    }

    // Los algoritmos que trae la libreria estandar te haran la vida mucho mas
    // facil.
    std::sort(digitos.rbegin(), digitos.rend());

    std::cout << "El mayor numero que se puede formar es: ";
    for (int digito : digitos) { // Este for es mucho mas bonito
        std::cout << digito;
    }

}
```

Si quieres investigar los temas sin usar ese código, serian:

- `for` loop
- Funciones
- Arrays
- Constantes y números mágicos
- La STL.

Answer (score 3):

Te complicas mucho la vida, sólo necesitas leer tres dígitos y ordenarlos de mayor a menor:

```
constexpr int cifras = 3;
char numero[cifras]{};

std::cout << "Pon un numero de " << cifras << " cifras: ";

/* Leemos un máximo de 'cifras' caracteres, la lectura puede fallar si hay menos
    por eso comprobamos el estado de 'std::cin' a cada vuelta. */
for (int cifra = 0; std::cin && cifra != cifras; ++cifra)
    std::cin.get(numero[cifra]);

/* Si el estado de 'std::cin' es correcto y
    el siguiente caracter es un retorno de línea y
    todo lo leído es un número. */
if (std::cin && std::cin.peek() == '\n' && std::all_of(numero, numero + cifras, [](char c){ return std::isdigit(c); }))
{
    // Ordena de mayor a menor.
    std::sort(numero, numero + cifras, std::greater<char>{});
    // Copia el resultado a la consola.
    std::copy(numero, numero + cifras, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
}
else
    // Si todas las precondiciones fallaron, no era un numero.
    std::cout << "No es un numero de " << cifras << " cifras\n";
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZLRboIwFIav6VOcuUTb6BY37wR8hGX3akxTCzbDlrQlmSE8O2uhILtY3F3zn/985xx@WFm@sILKvG2fhWRFdeaQCGWs5vS6Q3eNFrnSwl5@icJyTa3SU40xeyv5VMkqyaxQkhY7hIS0cKVCYoJqFDEljeXfpQavM5FpaiCFTexKF6pBVleu1b4vHOsmRigy9rzdMlVZSBKYfSoJlQxGcONmXg4kbwjvLcx8c6Y04HGWG7WOoQcKCfN5kJ/S0BXDctm9CIqiwfeac4unmx2JR4sM8BQ12kvOvzCBNIXFQS7GEi2Kk8oCaDVcsAyTV7A/4u4bMFKD5rbSsu8T5ixyYTEjMTTELVYPuxml7d@8zpK7XF1oiSfv6sYtPtylytuD3vBXnIbUewge8yCe1qCIF4bfsSGnDwXc/Cupg@ySCievY9S07dv7Bv0A)</kbd>.